# I have positioned the Bootstrap 4 "carousel-caption" as absolute. But when I do responsive mode it's not all responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  /* Make the image fully responsive */
  .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }

.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
top:113px;
left:150px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to bootstrap. I want the carousel caption to appear on the left. For that I used absolute positioning. But when I do testing in responsive mode, the text are responsive. It goes out of shape. Even I tried with transform:translateX(-50%). But I m not able to position for mobile devices and tablets.  Can someone please help me or guide me on this.

Comment: Did you try `text-align:left` ?

Comment: @samuellawrentz yes it's not working

Comment: use this css `.carousel-caption { top:113px; bottom: auto }` it works on mobile also, also can u add a screenshot of the expected result, that will be easier to get what u are looking for.

Comment: add class="text-left" to each H3 and P caption elements.